# Only one row is returned using where in with comma seperated value in Laravel raw query

Tags: laravel

I am developing a php project using Laravel 5.2. In my app I am retrieving records from database using manual query. But I am having a problem with retrieving records by using where in statement with csv.

Example how I am retrieving

```
$csv = "1,3,5";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `id` IN (?)";
$rows = DB::select($sql,[$csv]);
```

As you can see above I am retrieving three rows. But it returns only one row where `id` is 1. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it like that. Each entry in your csv is a separate parameter, so for your code you would actually need `IN (?, ?, ?)`, and then pass in the array of values. It would be pretty easy to write the code to do this (explode the string to an array, create another array of question marks the same size, put it all together).

However, you are using Laravel, so it would be easier to use the functionality Laravel provides to you.

Using the query builder, you can do this like:

```
$csv = "1,3,5";

// turn your csv into an array
$ids = explode(",", $csv);

// get the data
$rows = DB::table('items')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();

// $rows will be an array of stdClass objects containing your results
dd($rows);
```

Or, if you have an `Item` model setup for your `items` table, you could do:

```
$items = Item::whereIn('id', $params)->get();

// $items will be a Collection of Item objects
dd($items);
```

Or, assuming `id` is the primary key of your items table:

```
// find can take a single id, or an array of ids
$items = Item::find($params);

// $items will be a Collection of Item objects
dd($items);
```

### Edit

If you really want to do it the manual way, you could use a loop, but you don't need to. PHP provides some pretty convenient array methods.

```
$csv = "1,3,5";

// turn your csv into an array
$ids = explode(",", $csv);

// generate the number of parameters you need
$markers = array_fill(0, count($ids), '?');

// write your sql
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `id` IN (".implode(',', $markers).")";

// get your data
$rows = DB::select($sql, $ids);
```

Comment: Throwing this error. ErrorException in helpers.php line 686: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Comment: @WaiYanHein None of the code I have provided uses the helpers, so you probably have some other issue going on. Best bet is to post a new question with the pertinent code.

Comment: But I got the solution referencing on this. Thanks.